# How to replicate this table layout in HTML4/CSS2 (incl. vert-centered rows)

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I currently have a web page which is using tables to lay out rows of image links. The number of images per row may vary, and their dimensions may vary, yet each of them must be vertically centered across each row. Row heights therefore may vary too, depending on the tallest image in the row.

```
Example:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LM94B/

Given the required variability of image sizes, I have no idea how to replicate this in CSS, so that all the centering is maintained (each cell is horizontally centered too). Is using tables the only way to reliably achieve this with support for IE6 onwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need IE6 support, then yes, you are better off sticking with tables. But make sure you add `role="presentation"` as an attribute to the `<table>` elements so that modern screen readers know that they're not tabular data tables and don't attempt to call them out as such to their users.

Note that `role="presentation"` is invalid HTML4, but doing something useful for users trumps keeping validators quiet.

That's not to say that it can't be done at all. Here's a fully HTML4 valid tableless solution that works in IE6 and the latest browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test case</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    a { font-size: 10pt; text-decoration:none; color: #00f; }
    a:visited { text-decoration:none; color: #00f; }
    a:hover { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; }

    .page { text-align:center }
    .page .row { margin-bottom: 20px; }
    .page { margin-top: 24px; }
    .page a { 
        display:inline-block; 
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    .spacer {
        margin-left: 16px;
    }
    img { border:none; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="placeholder image"><br>Link 1</a>
            <span class="spacer"></span>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="placeholder image"><br>Link 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/180x80" alt="placeholder image"><br>Link 3</a>
            <span class="spacer"></span>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" alt="placeholder image"><br>Link 4</a>
            <span class="spacer"></span>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x100" alt="placeholder image"><br>Link 5</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

See http://alohci.net/static/imagerows2.htm

Comment: Thank you, that is awesome! This does indeed seem to work down to IE6. However, why do you still suggest keeping to tables if your solution works?

Comment: IE6 has so many rendering oddities, that keeping control is difficult. For example, a setting like `display:inline-block;` only works reasonably well in IE6 if it's applied to elements that are inline by default. That's OK in this example, but it's not always what you want. Layout of table markup is pretty reliable in IE6, as you have already found, so it is easier to stick with it. And it's not really *that* evil, so long as it doesn't cause problems for accessibility tool users.